# percentage of rows that match condition

Tags: mysql, database

I am looking for a way to get a percentage of rows that match a certain condition without utilizing subqueries. Currently, I have:

```
SELECT 
((SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `table1`
WHERE `date` >= @monthbegin AND `date` <= @monthend AND `isMember` = TRUE) / 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `table`
WHERE `date` >= @monthbegin AND `date` <= @monthend) * 100) AS percent_new
```

Basically, there are `N` new rows each month, and I would like to get the percentage of these new rows that match the condition where `isMember = TRUE`. Is there a shorter or cleaner way to do this?

Comment: There is.. its called subqueries... you are basically doing two subqueries that are identical as is.. why not just use a subquery?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the `table1` and `table` are actually meant to be the same.. you could try

```
SELECT 100*SUM(CASE WHEN `isMember` THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(*) percent_new
FROM `table1`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN @monthbegin AND @monthend
```

Absolutely no idea if this is faster than your query, but it does remove the subqueries.

You could also try:

```
SELECT 100*COUNT(CASE WHEN `isMember` THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)/count(*) percent_new
FROM `table1`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN @monthbegin AND @monthend
```

Actually, using the way `MySQL` treats `BOOLEAN` columns you can get away with:

```
SELECT 100*SUM(`isMember`)/COUNT(*) percent_new
FROM `table1`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN @monthbegin AND @monthend
```

Comment: @JohnRuddell I have updated the answer to use `BETWEEN` but not the extra parentheses.. it doesn't matter what order the operators are called (maths).